# Intervals in react with useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing a small multiplayer web game, and after completing the backend, I've turned my attention to the challenging frontend in React.

To summarize, it's similar to popular games like "Gartic Phone" or "Skribbl", where players connect to a lobby and start a game with their friends. Each game consists of multiple rounds, each with a maximum time limit for each player.

Currently, I'm working on implementing the time limit functionality for each round, and I'm facing issues with sending the player's input if they fail to press the send button within the allocated time.

### Let me show you the current situation:

```
function GameRound() {

    // ...
    const [timerTime, setTimerTime] = useState(30);
    const [sent, setSent] = useState(false)
    // ...

    let timerInterval;
    useEffect(() => {
        const decTimer = () => {
            setTimerTime((oldTimerTime) => {
                if(oldTimerTime === 1) {    // this statement is there because using "timerTime" outside the
                    if(!sent)             // set function would not use the correct "timerTime" current value
                        sendAnswer()
                }

                return oldTimerTime-1
            });
        };

        // ...

        sharedEventSource.addEventListener("game", (event) => {
            // ...
            timerInterval = setInterval(decTimer, 1000);
            // ...
        })

        // ...
    }, [sharedEventSource]);

    const sendAnswer = async () => {
        fetch("......", {/*...*/}); // send the answer to the server

        // ...

        setSent((oldSent) => {return true})
    }

    return (
        <>
            {/* ... */}
            <div onClick={sendAnswer}>send answer</div>
            {/* ... */}
        </>
    )

}
```

I have implemented the ***send answer*** button in the UI that allows players to submit their response to a question to the server before the timer expires. This triggers the ***sendAnswer*** function setting the "***sent***" state to true. Within the useEffect, there is an interval callback named "***decTimer***", which is initiated when the server sends the SSE event "game".

The purpose of "decTimer" is to decrement the "***timerTime***" value by 1 every second. If it reaches 0, the player's response is sent to the server.

---

*Note the "if(!sent)": I've included this condition to prevent "sendAnswer" from being called if the player has already submitted their answer by clicking the button.*

---

## What's the problem?

Upon reaching 0, the timer triggers the "if(!sent)" condition. However, regardless of the "**setSent**" call inside the "**sendAnswer**" function, The "**sendAnswer**" function is invoked again by the interval, even if the player has already submitted their answer. *(Additionally, when the interval calls "sendAnswer", the answer sent through the fetch request is just the default value set in the useState initial setup. However, when players trigger the function by pressing the button, the answer is sent correctly to the server.)*

I suspect this issue arises because the "sendAnswer" callback is declared outside the useEffect, but I'm struggling to find a solution!

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that I’m currently using the “sent” state to render dynamically the send button, as once pressed it will disappear. So I think it should stay a state

Comment: In your example code, your `sent` state is never `false` (it doesn't start off as false or doesn't get set to `false`). Did you mean to initialize it to `true` like you have or does it really start off a `false`?

Comment: Your issue though seems to be that the `(oldTimerTime) => {` has a "stale closure" over the `sent` variable. The values which that function has access to are the ones in its surrounding scope _at the time that the function is created_. Same goes for the functions that surround it (see [this](/a/77952011/5648954), [this](/a/78010667/5648954) and [this](/a/77913181/5648954) for a little more info). You might find that if your `sent` state doesn't need to rerender your component, or isn't being used in your UI (ie: JSX), then you can replace it to be a ref.

Comment: @NickParsons oh yeah I made a mistake in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` dependency is missing the `sent` state.

Therefore, the `sent` variable in the `decTimer` function is always false, even if you change `sent` to true in the `sendAnswer` function.

To solve this problem, you should use **useRef** instead of useState.

```
// original: const [sent, setSent] = useState(true)
const sentRef = useRef(false);

//...

const sendAnswer = async () => {
    fetch("......", {/*...*/}); // send the answer to the server

    // ...

    sentRef.current = true;
}
```

Comment: what if I need “sent” to be a state because its used to render a div?

Comment: then, use both "sent" state and "sentRef".

Comment: do you know how to get the right data when calling "sendAnswer" from the interval? It currently use the correct "answer" (which is a state) only if its called by clicking on the button. The call from the interval is using "answer" as default value set in the useState init because "sendAnswer" is created outside the useEffect

Answer (score 1):

You should use a useRef for your sentStatus.

```
    function GameRound() {

    // ...
    const [timerTime, setTimerTime] = useState(30);
    const sentStatusRef = useRef(false)
    // ...

    let timerInterval;
    useEffect(() => {
        const decTimer = () => {
            setTimerTime((oldTimerTime) => {
                if(oldTimerTime === 1) {    // this statement is there because using "timerTime" outside the
                    if(!sentStatusRef.current)             // set function would not use the correct "timerTime" current value
                        sendAnswer()
                }

                return oldTimerTime-1
            });
        };

        // ...

        sharedEventSource.addEventListener("game", (event) => {
            // ...
            timerInterval = setInterval(decTimer, 1000);
            // ...
        })

        // ...
    }, [sharedEventSource]);

    const sendAnswer = async () => {
        fetch("......", {/*...*/}); // send the answer to the server

        // ...

        sentStatusRef.current = true;
    }

    return (
        <>
            {/* ... */}
            <div onClick={sendAnswer}>send answer</div>
            {/* ... */}
        </>
    )

}
```

And I think if I had this problem. it's the backend that will put a random answer if someone didn't vote. because I find it a little weird to have the frontend that will trigger a useEffect for this issue. (Open to dicussion)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need sent to render a div, so it should be a state

Comment: btw I prefer to keep an incomplete answer of the client rather than an empty or random one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeOut` for the same and get your button disabled.
Here putting a start button just to trigger the event. You can modify according to your use case.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(30);
const [getZState, setZState] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
 if (counter > 0 && getZState === true) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setCounter(counter - 1)
    if (counter === 1) {
      setZState(false)
    }
  }, 1000);
}
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, [counter, getZState]);

  function handletrigger(){
      setCounter(30)
      setZState(true);
  }
```

//JSX

```
 <button className="startButton" onClick={() => handletrigger()}>Start</button>
 <div className="timerCount">Time Left:{counter}</div>

 <button disabled={counter === 0 ? true : false}>SEND</button>
```

Again when you need to triger the event you can use the same `handletrigger()`.